# Колёса, чудеса, небеса

Tags: грамматика, историческая-грамматика

Почему в русском языке, наравне со старославянизмами колёса, чудеса и небеса, не используются также и: телеса, делеса, словеса, древеса, очеса, личеса, удеса, чревеса и т. п. Неужели только из-за отсутствия оных в произведениях Пушкина?

Comment: Колёса, чудеса и небеса — не используются в русском языке? Так понимать?

Comment: @shampar наоборот используются, тогда как прочие остались не у дел, почему?

Comment: «...наравне со старославянизмами колёса, чудеса и небеса не используются», — слова из вопроса?

Comment: почему в русском наравне с одними старославянизмами не используются другие. то есть почему если вы скажите или напишите слово чудеса на Вас не посмотрят как на дурака, а если  скажите или напишите слово делеса на Вас могут посмотреть и спросить ты что ид..?

Comment: Это несколько другой ( про вопрос — ид...). Тот, что про Колёса, непонятен, непонятно сформулирован, и придётся его править Вам. Если интерес к проблеме неподдельный.

Comment: Я хотел бы добавить, что "словеса" и "телеса" используются в современном русском языке, но лишь в шутливом ключе. Как, например, в шуточном стишке Игоря Иртеньева: "Здесь можно трогать за валюту продажных женщин телеса."

Answer (score 3):

Это не старославянизмы, это древнерусские формы существительных, входившие в 5 склонение с основой на -ес.

История склонения имен существительных заключается в том, что на протяжении развития древнерусского языка вместо шести типов склонения установилось три типа, объединяющих существительные по роду, ранее распределенные по разным склонениям.

Утрата того или иного типа склонения обусловливалась относительной степенью продуктивности: в процессе сближения и взаимодействия победу мог одержать и одерживал более продуктивный тип по сравнению с менее продуктивным. Но утрата того или иного типа склонения не проходила в древнерусском языке таким образом, что этот утраченный тип исчезал совершенно бесследно: в русском языке всегда можно обнаружить определенные следы ранее существовавшего склонения.

История склонения на согласный.

Сущ. ср. р. на *-s ( **чудо, слово** ), совпав в форме Им. п. ед. ч. со словами ср. р. на *-ŏ ( село, молоко ), перешли в скл. *-ŏ с утратой древнего суфф. -ес- (при его сохранении в некоторых словах: чудеса, небеса, колесо).

Сущ. ср. р. на *-t ( телѧ, козьлѧ ) в форме м. п. ед. ч. приобрели суфф. -онок ( теленок, козленок ), сменили род на мужской и перешли в скл. на *-ŏ ;суфф. -ѧт- сохранился в формах мн. ч. ( телята, козлята ).

Сущ. ср. р. на *-n ( имѧ, сѣмѧ ) сохранили разные основы ( время – времени ) – разносклоняемые слова: в косв. п. имеют формы скл. на *-ĭ, в Тв. п. – -ем ( *-ŏ ).

Особенностью этого склонения было отпадение конечного согласного в силу действия ЗОС, а в связи с этим различные звуковые изменения. Так, в словах типа имя конечный ‘a восходит к е носовому, образовавшемуся в закрытом слоге; **конечный s отпал в основах на –ес (е выступало в чередовании с о: nebos – небо)**: т отпало в основах на –ят (теля – теляте): kamon дало kamun и камы; mater – мати.

**В остальных формах сохраняется согласный основы, и он легко выявляется (чудесный, небесный, древесный, телесный, колёсный, словесный )**.

Используется и форма тело-телеса (ироничн.), слово-словеса.

А вот чрево - это уже старославянизм с неполногласием -ре, а в древнерусском - черево, устаревшее.

Лице-лицесе, око - очеса оказались непродуктивными, видимо, из-за шипящего ч  и ц, потому и исчезли - из-за неблагозвучности, лицо, очи звучат гораздо лучше.

Устаревает то, что не используется носителями языка, а то, что используется, живёт.

Comment: Как на счет дуплета небо - нёбо? Почему в слове небо е не перешло в ё? Если верить в версию исконно русского слова небо, то следовало бы тогда объяснить этот момент.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что так получилось.

1. Не ясно, было ли употребление форм мн. ч. с *-ес-* чисто книжной чертой. Есть основания полагать, что оно не было чуждо и живой русской речи. Поэтому называть *старославянизмами* формы *чудеса, небеса* и проч., возможно, не вполне корректно.
2. В какой-то момент существительные древнерусского языка среднего рода с основой на согласный (с праслав. основами на *-ěs/*-ǒs) под влиянием сущ. со склонением на *ǒ утратили элемент -ес-, и появились формы типа слово — слова, словѹ; тѣло — тѣла, тѣлѹ.
3. *Небо — небеса*, но *слово — слова и (высок.) словеса*. Почему так получилось, можно только гадать. Видимо, *небеса* употреблялось исключительно в контексте обсуждений высшей материи, тогда как форму *слова́* можно часто встретить и в самом бытовом разговоре: «Слышь, слова фильтруй!»